# what happens when we use on_delete=models.CASCADE in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql-9.1

what happens when we use "on_delete=models.CASCADE" in django models

```
class HospitalStay(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What is unclear about [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE) for that option?

Answer (score 16):

`CASCADE` means that the row will be deleted too if the `ForeignKey` gets deleted.

In your case, `HospitalStay` instance will be deleted if the `User` Linked to it gets deleted.

[Read more on django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)